# `Interpreter died` error after updating Azure synapse spark pool

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I updated Synapse Apache spark pool from version **2.4** to **3.1** using the powershell script below;

`Update-AzSynapseSparkPool -WorkspaceName somewks -Name sparko1 -SparkVersion "3.1"`

The update was successful but i get `Interpreter died` Error everytime i run my notebooks. These notebooks works before the update. Has any one come across this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxRsU.png)

Comment: hi @john, I reproduced same thing in env. I didn't face any issue like `Interpreter died` error. Please edit and provide info about error and error snippet

Comment: Hello @BhanunagasaiVamsi, I have attached the error shot for you to take a look at. Thanks

Comment: @john Did you find the cause of this error, or a solution? I tried updating my pool from spark v3.2 to spark v3.3 using the REST API and now my notebooks are failing to start new sessions with the exact same error as yours.

Comment: @typheon it is like throwing darts at the wall for me at this point. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.  No luck with Microsoft support either.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Change the Apache Spark "Spark Pool" config in the Settings on the Notebook Activity in the pipeline to a different pool, publish. Change it back to the original pool, publish. This forces the config with the spark version to update the pool's current version, fixing the version mismatch.

This solution fixed our pipelines containing notebooks with minimal effort.

**Background & Details:**

We had a lot of pipelines in Synapse fail at my org.

Error codes to search:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not existed channel

Error: Interpreter died:

Root cause, Spark version recently got updated.
The Apache Spark pools in Synapse were upgraded to the newest version
Pipelines started failing, hit notebooks and die. Everything points to a config issue / version mismatch, when looking at the same error at other applications (read: other pyspark stuff that's not Synapse).

Issue (I believe) is that the Apache Spark configuration lives on the Notebook Activity in the pipeline. No way to directly update spark version for the notebook. This config is static unless forced to update, so it only exists on pipelines that had a Notebook Activity made with the old version of Spark.

You can test this by creating a Apache Spark pool on 3.2, creating a pipeline with a notebook using that pool, and updating the spark pool. The notebook activity will fail. Then create another notebook activity in the same pipeline in parallel, select the same pool. The new notebook activity will run fine, the old one will still fail. This determines the config lies with the notebook activity, so the solution was to change the pool to force the config to update.